# Larger Scrollbars

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, scrollbar

**Is it possible to enlarge scrollbars of SWT controls?**

I would like to change the size of all scrollbars that appear within SWT screens in my application.  This includes those that appear on tables, scrolled composites, text fields, etc.  Can these be modified graphically?

*Before:*

[image: Before]

*After:*

[image: After]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The scrollbar is handled by the OS, i.e. the OS decides how the scrollbar looks. You could draw a scrollbar yourself and hide the system one. That would involve a huge amount of work though.

You can read this tutorial if you want to know more about drawing stuff in SWT:

[Graphics Context - Quick on the draw](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-graphics/SWT_graphics.html)

Comment: Do you suppose that there is anyone who has already done such work using the information in the tutorial?  Maybe open-source code somewhere?  This seems like a problem other people might have had before me.

Comment: @SouthpawHare I don't think anyone has ever done this. To be honest, I can't think of any use-case that would make this necessary. The OS developers had good reasons to choose this size for the scrollbars.

Comment: Well, we are trying to make Mobile-friendly versions of our pre-existing Windows applications, which means basically making everything way bigger.

Comment: @SouthpawHare If it's mobile, can't you just scroll by dragging on the list/table/etc. rather than using the scrollbar?

Comment: Well, we can't figure out how to do that with SWT, either.  But that's a whole different problem =P

Comment: @SouthpawHare I'd have thought that Windows (or whichever OS you're using) would take care of that...